# Where is the KitKat Android GDK Preview?

Tags: android, gdk, aero-glass

Anyone know where the GDK preview add-on is?  I don't see it in the Android SDK Manager.  Is there a different repository that must be configured?  I have been developing with the GDK since it was first released, and I see the sneak peak, but not the preview.

I am using Eclipse.

Comment: It seems that the repositories were not updated when I tried to grab the new GDK.  After reloading (for the 16th time) it showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it's now available from the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDK Manager under Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

[image: Here is a screenshot]